# Как скачать зависимости для gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

Добавил зависимости в gradle.build. Но как их теперь скачать, чтобы работать с ними?

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0'
}
```

Comment: Он сам их подгрузит.

Comment: Как он сам их подгрузит? Я вот делаю обращение к классу из библиотеки, и не видит его.

Answer (score 3):

Надо добавить в build.gradle такую цель:

```
//copying all dependencies attached to 'compile' into a specific folder
task getDependencies(type: Copy) {
  //referring to the 'compile' configuration
  from configurations.compile, configurations.testCompile
  into 'libs'
}
```

from - перечисление конфигураций, для которых надо скачать зависимости.

into - каталог, куда скачивать файлы зависимостей.

После этого скачать зависимости можно командой

```
gradle getDependencies
```

Если после этого при компиляции возникают ошибки, значит зависимые библиотеки не добавлены в classpath